# Chrome HTML Inspector: Copy original source (and not modified DOM)

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, dom, web-inspector

I'm working quite a lot with HTML templates. many of those display more then just one visualization within one page. I therefore use chromes html inspector to copy the needed HTML source for a certain table/div from the template. I copy like this:

[image]

**BUT**: I found out, that copying from the HTML inspector actually copies the code from the DOM, which means that my copy of the code contains jquery modifications made by scripts and not the original source for a certain html-element.

Is there any way to copy that element with its sub-items and everything but from the source so that it does NOT contain any modifications of javascript dom manipulation!?

thanks a lot

---

**EDIT**: The only solution I found is by deactivating the execution of javascript temporarly in the inspector under "settings", then reloading the page and then copying the html-source for a certain node. But it's cumbersome and not really that nice...

Comment: Why not just do a view source the old fashioned way and copy from there?

Comment: Just use the "View Page Source" option and copy from that.

Comment: Sure but I really love to work with the inspector when working heavily with templates as I directly see which element to copy. That's why asking especially therefore... NOR do I have to search the element out of the complete source NEITHER do I need to select the innder elements...

Comment: Any possibility to EASILY find the ending tag for a certain element? I mean finding the starting div-tag is NOT difficult, but when the code isn't nicely formatted... it can be quite a tough task. And copying to a code formatter and then from there is really uncomfortable.. :(

Comment: HTML is not the DOM. the DOM inspector is not supposed to show you the original source; that's what View Source is for. If you need to find closing tags, use a professional code editor.

Comment: Yeah probably gotta do this then... Got notepad++, using TextFx Plugin to format the code properly helps quite a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION:

1. Ctrl+U -> Ctrl+A -> Ctrl+C -> Notepad++ Ctrl+V to paste it there.
2. Optional: Use the TextFX or Tidy Plugin to format the code quickly and maybe identify tags etc easier. But not necessary for Step 3:
3. Use the HTML Tag Plugin in notepad++ via Shift+Ctrl+T to select a HTML Tag until its closing tag (including opening and closing tag), see --> Just copy the selection via Ctrl+C

https://superuser.com/questions/174599/notepad-jump-between-opening-and-closing-html-tags

Answer (score 0):

Might seem a bit of a workaround, although if you use Chrome's Console logging, you can print the contents of a `<div>` upon load & before jQuery starts it's DOM modifications.

For getting this post's `.post-text` *before* modification:

```
console.log( $$('.post-text')[0].innerHTML );
$(document).ready(function(){
   /** Your JavaScript **/
});
```

[image: before Js]

To get a little more out of Chrome with this you could could even use it to [**Copy the HTML**](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#copyobject):

```
//Now press Ctrl + v where-ever you need to paste the contents.
console.log( 
    copy( $$('.post-text')[0].innerHTML )
);
```

Or a last suggestion, which will pause the page and inspect the elements within Chrome, where you can carry on with your inspector selections:

```
//or another div/selector.
inspect( document.body ); 
debugger;

$(document).ready(function(){
   /** Your JavaScript **/
});
```

Comment: And what when I haven't got access to modify the source of the HTML? This would require me to first look at which element I'd like to take out of the template, then modify the template by adding the `console.log( $$('.post-text')[0].innerHTML );` and then reloading it... :(

Comment: Well, What you'd be asking for is a "history" of a DOM's changes throughout it's manipulations right? I'm pretty certain no browser has that *natively*.

Comment: No Im simply asking to copy the original source. View source displays it. But copying it is quite tough for long div-tags which aren't nicely formatted...

Comment: Apologies then Tim, Alas I've not written a great answer for what you're asking for. I've added a final suggestion which pauses the JavaScript & page, where it opens up to a `<div>` with a provided selector, e.g. the `body`. Sorry that I couldn't help any further, I'll keep watch for other answers as I'm interested now too =)

Comment: No problem, thanks though. Im now copying the whole HTML source in Chrome to notepad and using the tidy plugin to tidy up the HTML Code nicely. Helps a bit but takes much more time then copying via the Chrome Inspector.. :) :(